# How to load a schema into Node-MySQL ClearDB Azure?

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, node-mysql, cleardb

I've got a schema that I want to load into  attached to my Azure/Node server:

```
USE mydatabase;

CREATE TABLE users(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40)
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
)
```

When the server connects using node-mysql, it says `ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE`.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

EDIT:
Here's the node code:

```
const mysql = require("mysql")

function connectToDB () {
  const connection_params = {
    host: process.env.db_host || "localhost",
    user: process.env.db_username || "root",
    password: process.env.db_password || "",
    database: process.env.db_database || "test_database"
  }
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(connection_params)
  connection.connect(console.log)
  return connection
}

module.exports = connectToDB
```

Comment: Do you use any ORM framework like sequelize? Please paste more details: codes, etc.

Comment: Using node-mysql, which negotiates connections between MySQL and Node, against which I can write SQL queries. So it's not an ORM.

Any other details you think I should add?

Comment: I knew node-mysql is a mysql driver for nodejs. Could you supply your node code to help testing the issue?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT I added the node code

Comment: I tried to test your code on my local mysql or azure cleardb, but didn't get any errors both. My steps:1.create a dir & npm install mysql in it; 2. remove the define header of function `connectToDB` & replace with my connect info & run it. Any more details can help reproducing your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed to get any errors when the server connects to local mysql and Azure ClearDB using `node-mysql`.  I suggest you to check the mysql carefully by using some third-party GUI admin tools like HeidiSQL for Windows or Dbeaver for any platform support Java.

You can download them at http://www.heidisql.com/ and http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/

I think you need to add symbol `;` for each JS sentences and use `var` instead of `const` for declaring a varibale  because of following the JavaScript Specification and the node-mysql doc, although it works fine without symbol `;` on NodeJS.

Please refer to these docs below:

- For semiconlon `;`:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements
- For `var` & `const`:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var and 
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const
- For node-mysql: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

When I connected MySQL and loaded table schema to create a table, I found that your SQL DDL sentence is not correct. Please refer to the mysql offical docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html.
Note: For date type `DATETIME` & `TIMESTAMPE`, the mysql offical docs says:

> DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP cannot be used with DATETIME columns.

So Here are the table ddl sql and code updated.

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40),
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection_parames = "mysql://user:password@host/test_database";

var connection = mysql.createConnection(connection_parames);

var table_ddl = "CREATE TABLE users ("+
    "id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
    "first_name VARCHAR(40),"+
    "last_name VARCHAR(40),"+
    "created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"+
    "PRIMARY KEY(id)"+
")";

connection.query(table_ddl, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```